# Create a Xcode 8 extension but no option on Xcode->editor

Tags: xcode

macOS 10.12, Xcode 8.1

I had created a Xcode extension like:
[Build your own Xcode 8 Source Editor Extension](https://medium.com/@victor_wang/build-your-own-xcode-8-source-editor-extension-5c728b1f3fa5#.si1m0h95k) and run it, but on the develop Xcode no option with my extension.

[image]

`System Preferences`->`Extensions` have my extension: [image]

What is going on？

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in signing -> just set automatic app signing and same profile on both targets (the extension and the target app)

You can check my article for creating Xcode extension in detail :)

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/xcode-extension-defining-enum-variables-swift-moreerror-bucher

Wish best luck :)